# Firebase and push nofitications

Tags: php, cordova, curl, stream, firebase

I've tried to let firebase manage all my data.
Everything is working fine, but I need to send a push notification to my users when a new content is added.

I was thinking about having a PHP server listening to any new firebase event, and sending a notification with a curl request.

The problem is that curl doesn't seem to be able to send a request (to the notification server) while streaming (listening to firebase events).

I've tried with `curl_multi_init`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

So here is my question: how I am supposed to deal with notifications and firebase? Can PHP do it?

Or have I to use another language ?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

For more information, I have added the code I try to use:

```
$master = curl_multi_init();


$ch = curl_init();
$curlToken = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://aweseome.firebaseio.com/plans.json?auth=XXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: text/event-stream'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'callBackFunction');

curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);
curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curlToken);

curl_multi_exec($master, $ch);
```

When using curl multi, the stream callback function is never called. If I use the normal curl, the stream function is called and is waiting for events, but I can no longer use another curl connexion to send the push notification.

How would you proceed? What language would you use if not php?

Comment: You seem to have tried some things. It will be easier for people to help if you share the code of those efforts, at least the minimum amount of code that pertains to the problem you're asking for help with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added code to describe my problem.

Comment: There is no "request to a notification server" in this code. Nor is anything listening to Firebase. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)